# Java - using Point class to return values of locations in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, class, point, maze

I am writing a program where I have a 2D array of objects from a cell class, and I need to write a method where I pass a cell object as a parameter and I return an arraylist of cells that surround the cell(N, S, E, W).  Each cell is given a location from the Point class.  What I am having trouble with is how to use the locations that I know(x, y-1 is north) to produce a cell.  Any help on this is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (x,y) is your cell then the four surrounding cells to it is

```
(x+1, y)
(x-1, y)
(x, y+1)
(x, y-1)
```

and you might make assumptions that

```
+x axis is EAST
-x axis is WEST
+y axis is NORTH
-y axis is SOUTH
```

so

```
(x+1, y) is EAST to the cell,
(x-1, y) is WEST to the cell,
(x, y+1) is NORTH to the cell and 
(x, y-1) is SOUTH
```

to the cell you pass as paremeter to your method.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  What I'm mainly having trouble with is how exactly to use the Point class with this.  So if I know that (x-1, y) is west of the cell, how can I get that cell so I can add it to an ArrayList.

Comment: yeah, as i told you, you have  to assume that which axis is which direction of map and you have to follow the assumption throughout your program.

Comment: I assume you meant -y is SOUTH, not WEST :) Though, it's common in some applications (particularly computer graphics) to make +y as south rather than north.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Thanks, i meant -y to be south. I have corrected the answer.